# Access to routeID in a FTP consumer when connection fails using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am using a FTP Endpoint in a Route, and I need to log the route details to database when the connection to ftp fails for some reason, like say a connection timeout or socket timeout.  I use a polling strategy, and the rollback method in this strategy gets called on a connection timeout.  But the rollback method does not give me access to the RouteID for me to log it to the database.

After doing some reason I found the flag consumer.bridgeErrorHandler which could be set to true to pass the exception to the default error handler.  But this just logs the error and doesn't solve my problem of how to get the route details.

Could someone help on how to get access to the routeID in the rollback method, or any other ideas you might have.

I am using apache camel 2.13.4

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own error handler and have custom logic to extract route details.  Example:

```
onException(SocketTimeoutException.class)
    .beanRef("myCustomErrorBean", "manageMyError")


public void manageMyError(Exchange exchange) {
    CamelContext context = //get this from exchange or inject it via spring or something
    context.getRoutes();
    //iterate the routes and you can check for the routeIds and anything else you like
}
```

Comment: I already have an OnException defined on the route, but when the exception happens at a consumer level and not inside the route this does not get executed.

Comment: Ah on the consumer level.  Camel has some interesting behavior when dealing with a consumer.  Here is an explanation of why and what you might be able to do to get custom error handling.  http://camel.apache.org/why-do-my-file-consumer-not-pickup-the-file-and-how-do-i-let-the-file-consumer-use-the-camel-error-handler.html

Comment: Yes, I went through the link before.  It looks like we could use only logging error handler, and default error handler.  Both of these don't give me an handle to the exception, and add custom code. I was wondering how I could write a custom error handler, but I couldn't find information on how to write one.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure if that feature set is possible on the FTP endpoint.  I would ask someone in the camel forums.  If you can't seem to get it working you can always use a quartz endpoint and use an enrich call on a camel route so the FTP component is inline with the route and the main error handler can have scope on the route